# Java Heap Memory Exception

Tags: java, mongodb, heap-memory

I am reading some huge data from some `csv` files and putting into database(`Mongodb`). But after reading some of the files i am getting heap memory error in java.I don't understand what is wrong with my program.The below is my program -

```
 import java.io.File;
    import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
    import java.io.FileReader;
    import java.io.IOException;
    import java.net.UnknownHostException;
    import java.nio.file.Files;
    import java.nio.file.Paths;
    import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
    import java.util.Date;

    import com.mongodb.BasicDBObject;
    import com.mongodb.DB;
    import com.mongodb.DBCollection;
    import com.mongodb.DBObject;
    import com.mongodb.MongoClient;
    import com.mongodb.MongoException;
    import com.mongodb.WriteConcern;

    import au.com.bytecode.opencsv.CSVReader;



    public class Csvread {
        MongoClient mongoClient = null;
        DB db = null;
        DBCollection coll =null;
        static Date myDate = new Date();
       public Csvread()

        {

           try {
            mongoClient = new MongoClient("localhost" ,27017);
        } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

           db = mongoClient.getDB( "mahout" );

           coll = db.getCollection("data_flowers_all");
            DBObject fields=new BasicDBObject("product_url",1);
            DBObject options=new BasicDBObject("unique",true);
    //      options.put("dropDups", true);
    //
            coll.createIndex(fields,options);
           coll.setWriteConcern(WriteConcern.UNACKNOWLEDGED);
        }

        public static void main(String[] args) {
            String parentPath="/media/bqadmin/D87CFB1B7CFAF35C/flowersjack/csv files";

            File parentFolder = new File(parentPath);

            String[] files = parentFolder.list();

          Csvread cvobj= new Csvread();

           try {
               for(String file : files)
                {
                   System.out.println();
                   System.out.println();
                   System.out.println();
                   System.out.println("files are:" +parentPath+File.separator+file);

                   CSVReader reader = new CSVReader(new FileReader(parentPath+File.separator+file),',','"');



           String [] nextLine;

             try {

                   while ((nextLine = reader.readNext()) != null &&nextLine.length!=0) {


                    Encapsulation encap=new Encapsulation();
    //         System.out.println("product name"+nextLine[1]);
                    encap.setId(nextLine[0]);
                    encap.setProduct_name(nextLine[1]);
                    encap.setProduct_url(nextLine[6]);
                    encap.setProduct_image(nextLine[3]);
                    encap.setProduct_price(nextLine[5]);
                    encap.setProduct_src("www.flowersus.com");
                    encap.setCountry("USA");
                    encap.setDate(myDate);
                    encap.setCategory(nextLine[8]);

                  cvobj.DBConnection(encap);

                  }

                  } catch (IOException e) {
    System.out.println("reading exception");
                 // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();

                   }
             try {
                reader.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                System.out.println("closing reader");
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            System.out.println("inside forloop");   
                }
               }catch (FileNotFoundException e) {

        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    System.out.println("filenotfound");
        e.printStackTrace();

        }

        }

        public void DBConnection(Encapsulation enc ) throws IOException{

        try {

        System.out.println("Inside database connectivity");

        BasicDBObject document=new BasicDBObject();

    //  System.out.println("BasicDBObject created");

        document.put("product_id",enc.getId());
    //  System.out.println("product_id is" +enc.getId());

        document.put("product_name",enc.getProduct_name() );
    //  System.out.println("product_name is" +enc.getProduct_name());

        document.put("product_url",enc.getProduct_url());
        System.out.println("product_url is" +enc.getProduct_url());

        document.put("product_img", enc.getProduct_image());
    //  System.out.println("product_img is" +enc.getProduct_image());

        document.put("product_price",enc.getProduct_price());
    //  System.out.println("price is" +enc.getProduct_price());

        document.put("country", "India");
    //    System.out.println("country" +enc.getCountry());

        document.put("date",new SimpleDateFormat("MM-dd-yyyy").format(myDate));

        document.put("category", enc.getCategory());
    //  System.out.println("categoriy is" +enc.getCategory());
    System.out.println(enc);
System.gc();//for clearing the object
        coll.insert(document);
        System.out.println("insertion complete");

        }

        catch (MongoException e) {

    System.out.println("duplicate");
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block

        e.printStackTrace();

        }
        }
    }
```

In this i have called System.gc(); to clear objects...Can anyone tell what is wrong with my program.Any help will be highly appreciable.....

```
public class Encapsulation {

        private String id;
        private String product_name;
        private String product_url;
        private String product_image;
        private String product_price;
        private String product_src;
        private String country;
        private Date date;
        private String Category;
        public String getId() {
            return id;
        }
        public void setId(String id) {
            this.id = id;
        }
        public String getProduct_name() {
            return product_name;
        }
        public void setProduct_name(String product_name) {
            this.product_name = product_name;
        }
        public String getProduct_url() {
            return product_url;
        }
        public void setProduct_url(String product_url) {
            this.product_url = product_url;
        }
        public String getProduct_image() {
            return product_image;
        }
        public void setProduct_image(String product_image) {
            this.product_image = product_image;
        }


        public String getProduct_price() {
            return product_price;
        }
        public void setProduct_price(String product_price) {
            this.product_price = product_price;
        }
        public String getProduct_src() {
            return product_src;
        }
        public void setProduct_src(String product_src) {
            this.product_src = product_src;
        }
        public String getCountry() {
            return country;
        }
        public void setCountry(String country) {
            this.country = country;
        }
        public Date getDate() {
            return date;
        }
        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return "Encapsulation [id=" + id + ", product_name=" + product_name + ", product_url=" + product_url
                    + ", product_image=" + product_image + ", product_price=" + product_price + ", product_src="
                    + product_src + ", country=" + country + ", date=" + date + ", Category=" + Category + "]";
        }
        public void setDate(Date myDate) {
            this.date = myDate;
        }
        public String getCategory() {
            return Category;
        }
        public void setCategory(String category) {
            Category = category;
        }

    }
```

Please note:after inserting data for some time ,the heap memory issue arises.

Comment: Calling System.gc() will *not* affect whether you run out of memory.

Comment: Can anyone suggest any method

Comment: What is your program doing when it runs out of memory?

Comment: it just shows running.cannot be able to terminate in console.But not taking datas(Simply stuck in console with some dialogue boxes showing out of memory errors).

Comment: increase your xmx value hope it may resolved your problem

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure, but it could be a memory leak in the Java-MongoDB-driver.
One possible way to resolve your issue and/or increase the performance of your code. Use:

```
public WriteResult insert(List<DBObject> list)
```

or any other method, which allows to add multiple data records at once.
(http://api.mongodb.org/java/2.13/)

I know, that u will have problems figuring out, what the duplicate entries are this way. I am not such much into MongoDB to know the best way to handle duplicate entries when adding multiple data records at once. But in your case, i definitly would try that approach.

**The second thing:**

Do the standard stuff to handle heap errors. Increase at least your heap size.
I dont know, how big your string arrays get, but it could be, that they make your too small heap explode. Especially with a bad implementation of CSVReader and a slow garbage collector.

Thats all guessing, but what isnt, when it comes to memory leaks... :)
Hope it helps.